# react can't access API docker-compose

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, api, docker-compose, proxy

I have three containers: MySQL 8, Spring Boot and React, and made the docker-compose.yml, totally based on Callicoder https://github.com/callicoder/spring-security-react-ant-design-polls-app

Also tried a dev environment version with npm start instead of build, and without nginx, and got nodejs api error ECONNREFUSED. However I can go to postman and use the api in localhost:8080 normally, so it's a docker container communications issue I guess, but have no clue how to solve it

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  app-server:
    build:
      context: olimpoback
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: always # "no" always unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/Olimpo?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: admin
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: senha
    networks:
      - backend
      - frontend
    #volumes:
    #  – /data/spring-boot-app

  # Frontend Service
  app-client:
    build:
      context: olimpoFront
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
      args:
        REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL: http://localhost:8080/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - app-server
    networks:
      - frontend

  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.0.21
    container_name: mysqlDB
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=Olimpo
      - MYSQL_USER=admin
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=senha
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=senha
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql-dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - backend

volumes:
  mysql_data:
    driver: local

networks:
  backend:
  frontend:
```

DockerFile(front end)

```
FROM node:14.15.1 as build

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install --silent && npm install react-scripts@3.3.0 -g --silent

COPY . ./

ARG REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL
ENV REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL=${REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL}

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.20.1

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

package.json

```
...
"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker's `localhost` isn't the same `localhost` you are trying to access using Postman. This happens because `app-server`, `app-client` and `mysqldb` are 3 distinct containers running in the same network. Each of them has its name.

So, to access your `app-server` from inside your container, you may use: `http://app-server:8080`

For example, take a look at your database url:

```
jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/Olimpo?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
```

You may notice that you are trying to access the url `mysqldb` instead of `localhost` for this same reason. You are referring to the database url as the container name.

You can take a deeper look [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Comment: I changed to app-server instead of localhost in package.json and REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL in docker-compose.yml, and still got the same issue

Comment: i made some changes, but still only work the dev environment version:
in docker-compose changed:
 dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      args:
        REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL: http://app-server:8080/
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
in applications.properties
spring.application.name='app-server:8080'
in package.json
"proxy": "http://app-server:8080",
however the production version still same issue